# what method that will called when we double tap on uitextview

Tags: methods, uitextview, copy-paste, cut, popover

if we double tap on UITextview, the textview will show a popover cut, copy, paste. I just want to now what method that will called when we double tap on uitextview so that popover appear??

**UPDATE**

finally i know what the method is. the real problem is i want to know, about the popover that contain cut,copy,paste,select, select all, replace. And that is a different controller that called by UITextView. That is UIMenuController. All the segment that show on that popover is set in UIMenuItem and this is an array. We can set what type of UIMenuItem that we want to show in `(BOOL)canPerformAction: withSender:` method.

This is my example code :

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {


    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: But what is the use to know this method any enhancement.

Comment: the question is i want to know, what class method or maybe delegate method that called to show the copy-cut-paste popover when i double tap the uitextveiw

Comment: not yet, i'm still doubt about that, textViewDidChangeSelection will fired if we move the cursor position, textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: will fired if we type something in textview, i still did not understand, what method that called the cut-copy-paste popover

Answer (score 1):

after double tap on the UITextview one of the delegate method `textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView*)textview` ll called.

Comment: is that method also called the copy-cut-paste popover??

Comment: textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:  will be called while cut-cut-paste popover..these are all coming under the "Responding to Text Changes" block in the UITEXTVIEW delegate..again finally the textViewDidChangeSelection ll be called